# Sum of a column that is already a sum

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

This is my query:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, sum(e.salary) AS total
from department d inner join employee e on d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name
```

I want the Grand total by sum of total column (the alias column). I get this by using this query:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, sum(e.salary) AS total
from department d inner join employee e on d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name WITH ROLLUP
```

But I want this by a another column, like using the sum function. Is it possible?

Comment: Why doesn't the `ROLLUP` work for you?

Comment: ypercube ----- I want this value an extra column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1:  Do you want the extra column to have only one entry, at the bottom?

Case 2:  Do you want a column with a running total that increases row by row?

For Case 1, there are two approaches:

1a: Do it in your application code; this is probably cleaner.

1b: You want to do it entirely in SQL:

```
SELECT ... (what you have, plus an extra column with an empty string) ...
UNION ALL
SELECT (a bunch of blanks, then SUM(to get grand total) ...
```

For Case 2, you need an @variable that keeps the running total:

```
SELECT ... SUM(e.salary) AS ..., @run := @run + SUM(e.salary) AS ... ...
```

To get @run initialized, you could either have a separate `SET` statement or fold it into this query by using a 'cross join':  `JOIN ( SELECT @run := 0 ) AS z` (with no `ON` clause).